# Why we use 'import' in React.js but 'require' in express?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I m so confused with this. In react application we use import keyword to import something...
but in express.js we use require keyword? why is that? please explain !

Comment: *Generally* because React apps use Babel + Webpack to enable `import` functionality, and not all Express/server-side apps do the same. There's no reason they *can't*, though.

Comment: I'm using express with `import` just fine.

Comment: Oh thanks... I was just wondering why is that but now it is making sense. ! thanks :)